# Xcode 3.2 says the version of iPhone OS isn't supported when my iPhone OS is version 3.1.3

Tags: iphone, xcode

I just went through the whole certificate/keychain/provisioning/appID/profile/DNA test process to get my app running on my iPhone.  Turns out my iPhone OS was out of date (3.0.1 I think), so I updated it.  Now it says

The version of iPhone OS on “Stefanie's phone” does not match any of the versions of iPhone OS supported for development with this copy of Xcode. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below. If necessary, the latest version of Xcode is available here.

OS Installed on Stefanie's phone
3.1.3 (7E18)

Xcode Supported iPhone OS Versions
3.1.2 (7D11)
3.1.1 (7C146)
3.1.1 (7C145)
3.1 (7C144)
3.0.1 (7A400)
3.0
2.2.1
2.2
2.1.1
2.1
2.0.2 (5C1)
2.0.1 (5B108)
2.0 (5A347)

But I have Xcode 3.2.1, which is supposed to support iPhone OS 3.1.3.  What am I doing wrong?  I have a cruddy internet connection (HughesNet), so I can't upgrade the Xcode SDK without it taking literally days.

Comment: Can't you do the download somewhere else where a faster connection is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have good news and bad news. The good news is that this is easily fixable. The bad news is that the fix is downloading the whole freaking package. I'm not sure why you can't just download the SDK and leave XCode alone, but Apple only supplies the SDK with all of XCode bundled with it - and the SDK version has to be greater than or equal to the version of your iPhone firmware.

Kind of a pain when dev builds come out every 2 weeks.

Comment: Ugh.  I'll have to do it at work.  And as we're a Microsoft only shop, I hope no one looks too closely at my download log.  2.3 GB can get noticed. 
I see now that I have the iPhone OS SDK version 3.1.2 and Xcode version 3.2  Is it just a coincidence that the currently available versions are 3.2 for Xcode AND 3.2 for iPhone OS SDK?  I find it odd that I have the latest Xcode with a version that matches the latest iPhone OS SDK, but not that same version of the iPhone OS SDK.  I leapfrogged it when I upgraded the phone OS.

Comment: Xcode and SDK versions are separate but confusingly similar in appearance - so yep, coincidence.